# How to target html area maps with css

Tags: jquery, css

I want to hide this area map with CSS. How do I do it without adding extra elements to it or around it?

```
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _hide_?

Comment: @Lashane Just css display:none

Comment: how it is displayed right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pointer-events on its own(Firefox do not take the display rule on map nor area tags)

```css
/* use the selector of your needs : 
img[usemap] or img[usemap="#planetmap"]
*/
img {
  pointer-events:none;
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<h1>map is disabled</h1>
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
```

Comment: Thank you, by the way how did you add the "Run Code snippet" button?

Comment: Do you use StackOverflow? It's automatic if you declare what language iti s. @nasty

Comment: it is inside the bar when you create a question or an answer  the <> button :)

Answer (score 0):

Append the CSS atribute `display`, set it to `none`, and place it inline inside the tag `map`:

```
<map name="planetmap" style="display:none;">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
```

or do it through a stylesheet, here's an example of the selector you could use:

```
map{

display:none;

}
```

**Edit:** And if you want to target the specific `name`:

```
map[name=planetmap] {    

display:none;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. how do I target exactly name="planetmap" ?